# R shiny selectizeInput get input value

Tags: r, shiny

I have the question about selectizeInput. If I have more selected inputs how can i get their values.  Exists some like input$selected[1],input$selected[2] ?
Thank you.

my code:

```
data<-data.frame(c("Mexico","China","Italy","Italy","Mexico"),c(120,130,125,140,145),c("Book","Table","Desk","Window","Rabbit"))

colnames(data)<-c("State","Count","Name")

    selectizeInput("mySelect",label="choose",multiple=TRUE,choices=colnames(data),
                   options =list(maxItems=2,plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop')))
```

And I need this for render

```
ggplot(data,aes(input$mySelect[1],input$mySelect[2]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `aes_string` and add a `geom` to your plot. But were you looking for something like this:

```
data<-data.frame(c("Mexico","China","Italy","Italy","Mexico"),c(120,130,125,140,145),c("Book","Table","Desk","Window","Rabbit"))

colnames(data)<-c("State","Count","Name")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("mySelect",label="choose",multiple=TRUE,choices=colnames(data),
                 options =list(maxItems=2,plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop'))),
  plotOutput('my_plot')
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {
  output$my_plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data,aes_string(input$mySelect[1],input$mySelect[2])) + geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```